# Protect a field in a UI from inserting chars or non-wanted characters except ints

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am building an MVC app and I currently have a troublesome problem.

So I have these lines of code:

```
<div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.m_Number, "OBJ Number")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.m_Number)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.m_Number)
        </div>
```

When I open my UI in this page, the field becomes a kind of textbox with arrows that I can click up and down to upgrade or diminish an int value; sorry for the poor description, but I don't find the exact word to describe it.

The main problem is that I can edit that field and, instead of putting numbers, I can write:

abl

And when I press enter, it "saves". The real saving hasn't occured because I do not send any information to a DB yet, but I want my UI to validate the type of data written in that field, I want to make sure only integers are written there and I don't know how to do this. I need help because I need to protect these fields from inserting the wrong data.

In my class I have already written this:

```
   [Display(Name = "Obj Number")]
        public int m_Number { get; set; }
```

But this does not solve anything.

Anyone has a clue on how I could do this? Thanks!

Comment: I think MaxLength can only be applied to `string` properties.

Comment: I corrected that, though that does not solve the problem at hand.

Comment: The more I dive into my code, the more it seems that the crash is non-relevant to this problem. I need to investigate further on.

Comment: In fact, I found out that the MaxLength attribute did provoke the crash when applied to an int. Good call @leppie!

Comment: Now I only want to find out how in the UI can I get it to validate if it's an int or not that's in the field and warn my user about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `pattern` attribute and set it to a regular expression that accepts only numbers:

```
$(function() {
    $('input[type="number"]').attr('pattern', '\\d*');
});
```

Bear in mind though that this is only for UI purposes. You should perform the necessary validations on the server because there's nothing preventing the user from simply using FireBug and submitting whatever value he wants to your server. This should not be used for validation purposes at all, only to assist the user.

Comment: Oh, interesting! I understand that it's only part of a solution, right? so I need to check with server validation?

Comment: You should **ALWAYS** have server side validation. Client side stuff is optional, only to improve the user experience.